# Implementing DFS in Open AI taxi env

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am new to the Open AI Gym environment and I want to implement Depth First Search to solve the taxi puzzle and I am having trouble getting the search working. I dont understand how I can get the possible actions.  Heres my current code:

```
env = gym.make('Taxi-v3',render_mode='human')
TE = TaxiEnv()

def dfs(state):

    taxi_row, taxi_col, passenger, dest = TE.decode(state)
    print(taxi_row, taxi_col, passenger, dest)
    if passenger == dest:
        path = []
    elif passenger == 4:
        path =+ [4]
    elif taxi_row == dest // 5 and taxi_col == dest % 5 and passenger == 4:
        action = 5
        path =+ [5]
        return path
    else:

        possible_moves = env.P[state]

        for action in possible_moves.items():
            next_state = action[1]

            path = dfs(next_state)
            obs, reward, done, tru, info = env.step(action)
            taxi_row, taxi_col, passenger, dest = TE.decode(obs)
            if path is not None:

                return [action] + path

    return None

env.reset()

state = env.action_space.sample()

print(dfs(state))
env.close()
```

Any help is appreciated